# JScrollPane not working correctly when adding JPanel (with FlowLayout) into JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I tried to add a `JPanel` (with `FlowLayout`) to a `JScrollPane` but the `ScrollBar` is not working. I want to place buttons as grid but it places horizontally.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        frame.add(pane);

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
            panel.add(new JButton("Label"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not use [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) instead of `FlowLayout`?

Comment: 1) Add all components. 2) Call `pack()`, ***then*** 3) `frame.setVisible(true);`. As to  the problem at hand, it sounds like a `JList` appropriately configured, would be the better approach.

Comment: You could also use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which is an extension of FlowLayout that allows components to dynamically wrap to the next row. The issue with this approach is that each component is displayed at its preferred size so it may not be a true grid if components have different sizes. Using a JList will provide dynamic wrapping and all cells will be the same size.

Comment: Don't remove relevant tags added by others. The [tag:layout-manager] tag is a 'parent' tag of all Java layouts (they all implement the layout manager interface). It's the same if they're inbuilt layouts or from 3rd parties.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to place buttons as grid but it places horizontally.

That's because you do not set the preferred size of the `JPanel` and because you add the `JPanel` to a `JScrollPane` you are effectively giving the `JPanel` infinite width and `FlowLayout` will lay out all its components in a single row until it reaches the width limit of the `JPanel` but because the width is infinite, all the `JButton`s appear on the same line. Also, because you set the horizontal scrollbar policy to NEVER, there is no way to scroll the `JPanel`.

You should call method `setVisible(true)` **after** you have added all the components.
Note that in the below code I use [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) rather than `FlowLayout` because `FlowLayout` will **not** display a grid of `JButton`. Also note that I call method `pack()` rather than method `setSize()`.

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 10, 5, 5));

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
            panel.add(new JButton("Label"));
        }
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture:

[image]

Note that, by default, `JScrollPane` will size itself so as to display all the `JButton`s. If you want the `JScrollPane` to only display a few rows, then you need to set its preferred size, for example

```java
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(710, 150));
```

### EDIT

If you **insist** on using `FlowLayout` then you need to set the preferred size for both the `JPanel` and the `JScrollPane`.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(710, 315));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("Label"));
        }

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 160));

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture.

[image: another screen capture]